Wpf DataGrid Formating
There are some features of DataGrid which i want to format.

How to remove it ?
I tried set border bottom for header but it just shown short line.
Row 15 is the last, but scrollbar can scroll over row 15th.

I tried set many properties but it did not show right because i don't know exactly property names.
Please help me review this.
Thanks in advance!

